# How to Enum get a index of a ecto member elixir phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm looking how to get a custom index of my ecto members in html show - generated from a resource `mix phx.gen.html` The goal is that every new `post` should have number. I have tried to create that function in PostsController, but I couldnt sort it out.

```
<%= for post <- @posts do %>

<%= post.title %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and welcome to Stack OverFlow :)

I'm pretty sure you are looking for:

```
<%= @posts |> Enum.with_index() |> Enum.map(fn({post, index}) ->  %>

  <%= index %>

  <%= post.title %>

<% end %>
```

In that way `<%= index %>` should point every ecto member and sort them.

Best Regards, ykostov

Comment: as good practice it is recommended to always include () to function calls, even if it doesn't have parameters.

Comment: yeah, that is important, but not so wrong in this case, isn't it? :) (answer edited)

Answer (score 2):

Variant with for:

```
<%= for {post, index} <- @posts |> Enum.with_index() do %>
<%= index %>
<%= post.title %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: yeah, with `for` for me is simpler, +1 from me